# MySQL Query to find matches between 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to write a query to find matching records between two tables. One table is a temp table with records created from an import and the other is the fixed table of user account summaries.

**Fixed Table**:

```
CREATE TABLE `system`.`hashTable` (
    `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `userID` int,
    `userHash` char(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `acctID` FOREIGN KEY (`userID`) 
        REFERENCES `system`.`master_accounts` (`accountID`)   
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE `hash` USING BTREE (`userHash`) comment ''
);
```

**Temporary Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `system`.`TEMP_TBL` (
    `id` int NOT NULL,
    `compHash` char(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `hash` USING BTREE (`compHash`) comment ''
);
```

The goal is to return the userID's which have matching records from *TEMP_TBL.compHash* in *hashTable.userHash*. The fixed table can have millions of rows and the temporary table can have up to 2000 rows.

I can find example of how to find non, matching records, but none for matching. I'm sure it's pretty simple but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a simple left join?

```
SELECT id FROM temp_tbl
LEFT JOIN hashTable
ON temp_tbl.comphash=hashTable.userhash
```

Answer (score 0):

`exists` is a perfectly reasonable solution:

```
select tt.*
from system.temp_tbl tt
where exists (select 1
              from system.hashtable ht
              where ht.userhash = tt.comphash
             );
```